# Numpy as_strided() segmentation fault

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to 'patchify' images with stride smaller than patch size (i.e. such that they will overlap). My way to do that was to read array and use [as_strided()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html?highlight=as_strided#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided), then copy values to new array. It works for images in uint8 format, however, when using on float32 it throws segmentation fault error. MWE:

```
import numpy as np

def patch_sample(arr, patch_size=(128, 128), stride=64):
    arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)
    H, W, C = arr.shape
    h, w = patch_size
    patches_h = int((H - h) / stride + 1)
    patches_w = int((W - w)/ stride + 1)
    new_shape = (patches_h, patches_w, h, w, C)
    new_strides = arr.itemsize * np.array(
        [
            W * arr.strides[1] * stride,
            arr.strides[1] * stride,
            W * arr.strides[1],
            arr.strides[1],
            1
        ]
    )
    patches_out = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr,
        shape=new_shape,
        strides=new_strides,
        writeable=False
    )

    # Here segfault occurs
    patches_out_cp = np.ascontiguousarray(patches_out)

    # Segfault as well:
    # patches_out_cp = patches_out.copy()

    # Same for:
    # patches_out_cp = np.empty_like(patches_out)
    # np.copyto(patches_out_cp, patches_out)

    patches_out_cp = patches_out_cp.reshape((-1, h, w, C))

    return patches_out_cp

# No segfault
test_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 1500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
print(patch_sample(test_array).shape)

# Segfault
test_array = np.random.rand(1000, 1500, 3).astype(np.float32)
print(patch_sample(test_array).shape)
```

Not sure what may be the reason for that. Any help would be great!

Comment: It may help if you showed `new_shape` and `new_strides`.  But I suspect a memory error.  `as_strided` creates a `view`, a new array which references the original.  But `ascontiguousarray` has to make a copy, an whole new array.  That can easily blow up, especially with 2d arrays.

Comment: For the given example of array (image) of size `(1000, 1500, 3)` we have the following: `new_shape = (14, 22, 128, 128, 3)` and `new_strides = itemsize * [1500*3*64, 3*64, 1500*3, 3, 1]`. For uint8 it works out well, i.e. I obtain copy of patches from the image. I think that the resulting array should work out to ~60MB (float32) for the given example, that's why memory error is quite surprising to me.